# Matrix Client-Server API: easiest way to get message count by room?

Tags: matrix

I'm a member of a Matrix instance. I would like to get a count of how many messages have been sent in a specific room. I've been looking around the [API documentation](https://playground.matrix.org/), and I don't see an obvious way to do this in a single call (the closest was the [search API](https://playground.matrix.org/#post-/_matrix/client/v3/search), but you can't have a wildcard or regex as a search parameter, you have to specify a real term).

That leaves me with the "solution" of calling the [/rooms/id/messages](https://playground.matrix.org/#get-/_matrix/client/v3/rooms/-roomId-/messages) endpoint in a loop until I've iterated over every single event. I think the room I'm interested in has dozens if not hundreds of thousands of messages, and a call returns at most 10 events, so it sounds like it's going to take a while. Is there a better way?